# horizontal scrolling of a scrollView in a scrollView - small problem

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touchesmoved

i have a scrollView that fits the whole screen. In that View i show some UIImages that scroll horizontally. Like in the PageControl Project from Apple.
Then, when the user taps the screen, i fade in a scrollView at the bottom with some other images. Also horizontally scrolling. Like in the ScrollView Project from Apple.

My problem is, that when i come to the end of the scrollView which was faded in, the upper scrollView also starts to drag. How can i stop that during activation of the second scrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redraw the frame limits on your first scrollView when the second enters the screen. That way, your touches won't respond to both views. This means you need a container-view to keep both views seperated from each other.

Then you just rescale it back whenever your second scrollView disappears.

Edit: or disable scroll in your first scrollview while the second is open.

Comment: Tried it with scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE; but i see no reaction. When i change the frame limits, doesn't it distort my image in the scrollView?

Comment: Ah okay, so you have an underlying image that should be somewhat covered by the second scrollView? The best approach is (imo) to disable scrolling in the first scrollView. I'm not at my mac now, so I can't go into specifics, I'm afraid

Comment: Ja, the second scrollView just lies above the first scrollView. But only a small row at the bottom.

Comment: have you tried just removing user interaction with the scrollView?

Comment: odd. I'm sorry, but I can't seem to help you :\